# Pygame does not detect Mouse presses

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

I am building a simple python script that runs functions that control the [Unicorn HAT](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/unicorn-hat) on the RPi. My Intention is to control this using mouse clicks.

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get()
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                if upRun or tRun == 1: #Cancel any scrollers
                    upRun = 0
                    tRun = 0
                n()
            elif event.button == 2:
                up()
            else:
                art()
```

On testing this I receive no output. Note I have called `pygame.init()` as required.

Polling all events results only in empty events.

Comment: Is this the way the indentation in your code looks? Because the indentation in your `for` loop is incorrect

Comment: Well catched. Yes the indentation is different, it currently runs fine.

Comment: Did you remember to set up display properties? If not, that's probably why (no display, no events)

Comment: Thanks jDo. Having tried that earlier to no success I ruled that out, but works now.

Comment: @Iceblue Ok, odd. Anyway, glad it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something tells me that you didn't set up any display properties. I could be wrong but this works for me:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                if upRun or tRun == 1: #Cancel any scrollers
                    upRun = 0
                    tRun = 0
                n()
            elif event.button == 2:
                up()
            else:
                art()
```